# MS Access Runtime closes database when there is a mirror error. How to Ignore?

Tags: vba, microsoft-office, macros, microsoft-access

There is a MS Access Database. Sometimes there are pop ups errors: "The value you entered isn't valied for this field" and then a Macro error. But that's OK, I just click "Stop All Macros" and give it another try.

But with MS Access 2016 Runtime it's different. The database just closes. How to make it behave the same way as full MS Access 2016? I don't want to database being closed when there is a minor error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add OnError macro handlers to your macros:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/onerror-macro-action-942d771c-6c1c-4cb3-afb1-ce9289d81913

It's only un-handled errors that cause the runtime to exit.